# Derive a new Sphinx index from an existing Sphinx index as the data source?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to index a large MySQL data table of products with a daily cron job.  When a new products index is created, I would also like to create an index of merchants with the top n products, using Sphinx's multi-valued attribute (MVA).  It's a relatively simple grouping operation.  Is there a way to instruct Sphinx to use it's own index (the product index mentioned above) to create another index (the merchants index)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but might sort of be possible. Frankly its probably more hassle than just creating the second index direct from mysql as well.

Sphinx doesnt really store the original text when building an index. So would need to duplicate all the required columns as attributes, so that the data would be stored. You could then build a second index, by running sphinxQL command (in sql_query).

You might also run into issues with max_matches, unless you get creative with ranged queries.

SO as its not a build in feature, will be hard to make it work well.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I ended up creating a PHP script to build a temporary MySQL table combining required information from the first Sphinx index and MySQL products table, indexing the temporary table with Sphinx to produce my merchants index and then discarding the temporary table.  I did not want to repeat a variation of the initial indexing operation because it takes a couple hours.